# Visual Studio keeps auto filling even with intellisense turned off

Tags: c#

Visual Studio 2017 keeps filling out code sometimes even with intellisense turned off. I'm trying to learn C# and I'm copying examples from the book, Visual C# How To Program sixth edition, and just going through them and reading the book.

Sometimes auto complete really screws things up and I don't know what I need to turn off. Here is an example with a line of code.

```
   public override decimal Earnings() => WeeklySalary;
```

But when I try to put this in Visual Studio I get to the () and it does this.

```
    public override decimal Earnings()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();)
    }
```

This really messes things up when I am looking at the code I'm trying to copy and not the screen. How do I stop this?

Comment: That's not intellisense. Other extension are doing it. Can you list the active 3rd party extension installed?

Comment: smells like reSharper

Comment: I went to tools and then extensions and updates and it looks like there are over thirty of them. Is there one in particular that I'm looking for?

Comment: I don't see reSharper

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you're describing is called "statement completion" in Visual Studio. It's different than Intellisense. Try changing things in the "statement completion" section of the C# properties for the Text Editor:

[image]

My guess is that "automatic brace completion" is the box you'll want to uncheck.

Comment: Hmmm... playing with this - I'm now not sure. I'm now thinking that @Martheen might be correct - this feels like an extension.

Comment: Thank you Adam. I will look at those settings.